# Oracle: insert new row if previous row values are different from current row values. Else, update

Tags: sql, oracle, insert, row

In the PLSQL,I have a table A with three columns: product, amount, date.

Table A:

```
 Product-  Amount- Date

1S        100     1/1/2005
1S        100     1/2/2005
1S        100     1/7/2005
1S        120     1/10/2005
```

As we can see for the one product, the amount 100 is same for all 3 dates. And also, 3 records are inserted.But instead of 3 records, if the amount of current row is same as previous row, then we need to just update DATE and no new records should be inserted.

If the current row contains a new amount 120 and not same as previous row, then a record should be inserted. Please see the below output that am expecting

**Output:**

```
 Product   -Amount         - Date

1S           100         1/7/2005   
1S           120         1/10/2005
```

Comment: Go read up on MERGE statement.

Comment: Do you mean you need to insert the highest record  into another table or you want to delete the 2nd and subsequent records  in tablea? Because updating cannot mean you end up with 2 rows as you have shown.

Comment: Hi Kaushik, Everyday i get a new record from another main table "B" with product, amount, date. Based on the table B record, we need to compare whether that amount for that product ( date is always different) is already exist in table A or not. if exists, then just update date in table A. Else, insert new record.

Comment: You could always use merge if you want to update if condition is satisifed or else insert. See below
Merge into tableA tgt
using (select product, amount, date from table B) src
on(src.product = tgt.product and src.amount = tgt.amt)
when matched then update tableA
When not matched then insert into TableA

Comment: Thanks a lot Praveen. It worked. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as below. This would give the max date grouped by product and amount.This would be a simple query than merge

```
insert into tablea
(select product,amount,max(date) from tableb
group by product,amount).
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Praveen